# Analysing the result of LSTM Theano Sentiment Analysis

Tags: sentiment-analysis, deep-learning, lstm

I'm trying the code from this link http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lstm.html but changing the imdb data to my own. This is the screenshot of my result.

[image]

I want to determine the overall accuracy of running LSTM for sentiment analysis, but cannot understand the output. The train, valid and test values print multiple times but it's usually the same value.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The value it prints is computed by the following function:

```py
def pred_error(f_pred, prepare_data, data, iterator, verbose=False):
    """
    Just compute the error
    f_pred: Theano fct computing the prediction
    prepare_data: usual prepare_data for that dataset.
    """
    valid_err = 0
    for _, valid_index in iterator:
        x, mask, y = prepare_data([data[0][t] for t in valid_index],
                                  numpy.array(data[1])[valid_index],
                                  maxlen=None)
        preds = f_pred(x, mask)
        targets = numpy.array(data[1])[valid_index]
        valid_err += (preds == targets).sum()
    valid_err = 1. - numpy_floatX(valid_err) / len(data[0])

    return valid_err
```

It is easy to follow, and what it computes is `1 - accuracy`, where accuracy is percentage of samples labeled correctly. In other words, you get around 72% accuracy on the training set, almost 95% accuracy on the validation set, and 50% accuracy on the test set.

The fact that your validation accuracy is so high compared to the train accuracy is a little bit suspicious, I would trace the predictions and see if may be our validation set is somehow not representative, or too small.

Comment: I see. The only thing I changed was the input data. I preprocessed it according to instructions and converted it into pkl file. Does the problem lies with my data? I also implemented lstm with keras and got 86% accuracy there. What went wrong here?